# Pig dump cannot take expressions?

Tags: apache-pig

It appears that I cannot do

```
dump (limit A 10);
```

while

```
B = limit A 10;
dump B;
```

seems to work.

Why? This seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: Pig consist of three phases, LOAD, TRANSFORM, DUMP/STORE (ETL), in that example you're trying to perform a transformation in STORE phase, additionally, The nature of Pig itself tells you that for every single operation on the pipeline you have the outcomes to be assigned into a relation before using them afterwards (I am not completely sure of all of that, I'm completely new to Pig)

Comment: That is not true. You can still do "STORE (expression)..." or "FOREACH (GROUP ...) GENERATE...". It is not true that every single operation (I guess a pig statement was meant) should have its relation name, because it is not necessarily a single MapReduce job, sometimes Pig merges many statements into a single MapReduce job. I guess that this particular DUMP (expression) case is a limitation/bug of Pig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed the case that you cannot do this.

I believe that the question of why is not really in scope, but perhaps it is because unlike `STORE`, the `DUMP` command is mainly for debugging.

Perhaps related:
If you just type `DUMP` without any argument, it will automatically dump the last used alias.